# "Whether" Vs. "If"

Tags: whether-if

Could someone please help me with these sentences?
I need to know

1. Which one doesn’t sound natural?
2. Which one is formal and which one is not?

> A - I don’t know **whether** this word fits in the sentence.
> B - I don’t know **if** this word fits in the sentence.

> C - I don’t know **whether** **or not** this word fits in the sentence.
> D - I don’t know **if** **or not** this word fits in the sentence.

> E - I don’t know **whether** this word fits in the sentence **or not**.
> F - I don’t know **if** this word fits in the sentence **or not**.

For me only D doesn't work and sounds not idiomatic. Meanwhile for me all of these sentences can be used in both written and spoken languages.
Do you confirm me?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**
You are exactly right; (D) is not usually acceptable<sup>†</sup>, but all the others are.

There are however other circumstances in which *whether* and *if* are used somewhat differently, and different rules apply.

**LONGER ANSWER:**
You raise, in effect, three distinct questions:

1. **When may** *if* **be substituted for** *whether***?**
   This is an easy one: *if* may always be used in **any** expression which employs  *whether*. (But as we will see, some syntactical adjustments may be required.)
2. **When is** *or not* **permitted or required in expressions with** *whether* **and** *if* **in that sense, and how is it deployed?**
   *Whether* and *if* are used to introduce clauses expressing a choice between two or more alternatives in two contexts:

   - In **complement clauses**

     > I need to know **whether** this word fits in this sentence **or** does not fit in this sentence **or** fits only sometimes.
     >   I need to know **if** this word fits in this sentence **or** does not fit in this sentence **or** fits only sometimes.
     >
     > I need to know **whether** this word fits in this sentence **or** does not fit in this sentence.
     >   I need to know **if** this word fits in this sentence **or** does not fit in this sentence.

     In situations like the second pair, where there are only two alternatives and one is simply the negation of the other, you may replace the second alternative with a bare *not*:

     > I need to know **whether** this word fits in this sentence **or not**.
     >   I need to know **if** this word fits in this sentence **or not**.

     In fact, you can omit the **or** clause altogether; the absence of an explicit *or* implies that the negative is intended:

     > I need to know **whether** this word fits in this sentence.
     >   I need to know **if** this word fits in this sentence.

     The phrase *or not* may be moved immediately after *whether*, but this is **not** generally used<sup>†</sup> with *if*:

     > <sup>ok</sup>I need to know **whether or not** this word fits in this sentence.
     >   <sup>??</sup>I need to know **if or not** this word fits in this sentence.
   - in **condition clauses**
     When *whether* and *if* are used to head the ‘protasis’ (*IF* or condition clause) in a conditional construction, the rules are different.

     With *whether*, there **must** be an explicit **or** clause or phrase:

     > <sup>ok</sup>Whether the word fits **or** does not fit, spell it correctly!
     >   <sup>ok</sup>Whether the word fits **or not**, spell it correctly!
     >   <sup>ok</sup>Whether **or not** the word fits, spell it correctly! ... *BUT*
     >   <sup>∗</sup> Whether the word fits, spell it correctly!

     And *if* cannot be simply substituted for *whether* in a condition clause, because in that context *whether* implies that the consequence is true or actualized if *either* condition is in force. You have to employ an *if* clause that expresses that meaning. With just two alternatives you may employ either *or if* or *both if...and if*:

     > If the word fits or if it does not, spell it correctly!
     >   Both if the word fits and if it does not, spell it correctly!

     These are grammatically and logically sound, but clunky; and there really is no graceful way to express three or more alternatives using *if*, since the introductory *both*, which alerts the reader to the structure which will follow, is not applicable. Stick with *whether*.
3. **Are these uses of** *if* **restricted to informal use?**

   It's not really a matter of formality v. informality, but of monologue v. dialogue. In conversation, where any misunderstanding is easily corrected, *if* is entirely acceptable.

   But in writing, or in spoken contexts such as lectures and broadcasts which do not involve participation by the hearer, you want to make what you are saying as easy for the addressee to ‘process’ as possible. The “rule” here is to use the most explicit term possible. Since *if* has a very broad range of syntactic and semantic meanings, while *whether* has a relatively narrow range, your choice should always be to use *whether* rather than *if* in circumstances where either is acceptable.

   And there is really no reason to avoid following this practice in conversation as well. It will not mark your speech as pedantic or highfalutin—everybody understands and uses *whether*.

   ---

<sup>†</sup>FumbleFingers points out that this use does appear from time to time, but acknowledges that it sounds “strange”. That, to my mind, means ‘Don’t use it’.

<sup>∗</sup> *marks an utterance as ungrammatical.*

Comment: I *may* be wrong here (and of course it all depends on exactly what we mean by "ungrammatical"), but I'm not entirely convinced *ungrammatical* is the right word there. I completely agree *"Whether the shoe fits, wear it!"* doesn't sound at all "good" to my ear, but it seems to me ***non-idiomatic*** describes it better.

Comment: It's a bit like *whichever/whatever* as opposed to *which/what*, in that you can say *"Whichever you want, just tell me and I'll get it for you"*, but somehow it doesn't work if we just try to use ***which*** there. I can only think this is a matter of idiomatic familiarity, not grammar as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers On the one hand, everything may be regarded as grammar; on the other, everything may be regarded as idiom. My canon of 'ungrammaticality' is whether I can formulate an explicit generally-observed grammatical rule which excludes it: that *whether* in conditional clauses requires an explicit *or-* complement, just as a transitive verb requires a direct object.

Comment: *Whichever/which* is interesting. I remember that McCawley has an entire chapter on issues of this sort, which I didn't get around to before the book had to go back to the library. He may have a 'grammatical' rule covering this. It may line up with his distinction between free relatives and embedded questions.

Comment: Thanks to [John Lawler's](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/2893/john-lawler) generosity (he gave me his old spare copy), I can confirm McCawley does indeed devote considerable attention to the usage, under what he calls "Alternative Questions". I must be more accommodating than the average Anglophone though. According to him, *"He asked **whether** we'd like more coffee"* is "questionable" (he flags it with a *single* question mark), but it seems absolutely fine to me. Unlike the asterisked *"He asked me **whether** I'd pass the salt"*, which I agree is *way* beyond the pale.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Useful. I think a single ? in McCawley means, basically, "some people don't like this". I agree with you. But I would have no objection to *"He asked me whether I was going to pass the salt he'd asked for three times already".* In any case, that's a  different question: When can *whether* be substituted for *if*?

Comment: My bottom-line position is that really you'd covered 99.99% of it with your "longer answer #1". Grammatically they're always interchangeable, but *idiomatically*, there are a few contexts where ***whether*** is slightly (or even *extremely*) less likely to be used. The only problem being no-one seems to be able to find a clear-cut explanation of *why* those "exceptions" exist, or how exactly to define them. Which is odd, given there's fairly consistent agreement among native speakers about which constructions *are* examples of those exceptions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers They're only 'always interchangeable' in one direction; *whether* can only rarely be substituted for *if*. For instance, you can't say ***Whether** you pass the salt shaker, make sure the holes are facing up*.  The real odd-man-out is that *if or not*: certainly we *could* say it, but the fact is we don't. It's been on the ballot for a long time, and the voters just don't like it.

Comment: Huddleston and Pullum put it this way: there are two words with the shape *if*.  One of them is a subordinator interchangeable with *whether* ("See **if/whether** there are any vacancies").  The other has a conditional meaning and is not interchangeable ("I'll help you **if/\*whether** I can").

Comment: @snailplane I'm very fond of Evil Twin plots.

Comment: Use of "if" could be better than "whether" in the context of the "if the word fits" example if the positive and negative expectations were unbalanced, e.g. "If the word fits--or even if it doesn't--spell it correctly".  Unbalancing the possibilities with the adverb *even* only really works with "if".

Comment: @StoneyBonhiatus Why we can't say **Whether you pass the salt shaker, make sure the holes are facing up.**.

Answer (score 5):

There's no grammatical rule to say any of OP's variants are "incorrect". For example...

> *There haven't been enough studies to determine [**if or not**](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Vv2sYeB_lrAC&pg=PA282&dq=%22if%20or%20not%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RPtcU9bQIKOX7Qa2roGIDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22if%20or%20not%22&f=false) there truly are negative effects...*

It's just that idiomatically we don't use that form so often, so it may appear "strange". But here are a few hundred instances of [*decide if or not*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if%20or%20not%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22decide%20if%20or%20not%22&tbm=bks) if you want to practice getting more used to that version.

---

In light of StoneyB's answer (and comments thereto), I think it's worth pointing out that [James McCawley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_D._McCawley), in what's probably the *definitive*  reference book [The Syntactic Phenomena of English](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Syntactic-Phenomena-English-James-Mccawley/dp/0226556298) devotes several pages to this particular usage. At the end of which he writes...

> *I suggest a deep structure like [what he's just set out] **without enthusiasm**, but also without any idea of how else the different kinds of [alternative questions](http://amor.cms.hu-berlin.de/~haidaand/download/Haida_2009_SuB14.pdf) could be given an analysis that is at all unified.*

Effectively, what McCawley is concluding there is that undeniably native speakers do have commonly-agreed preferences about contexts where ***if/whether*** are *not* interchangeable, but no-one (including him) can come up with a coherent "grammatical rule" to describe what exactly governs our thinking.

Mostly I think what this amounts to is ***if*** is such a short, common word that we've gotten used to using it in a wider variety of "conditional" contexts. But ***whether*** remains far more tightly bound to *"binary choice, yes or no"* contexts, so it's best to avoid it unless the single alternative *(or not)* is explicitly specified.

Comment: True; but according to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+or+not%2Fwhether+or+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28if%20or%20not%20/%20whether%20or%20not%29%3B%2Cc0) we're currently running about 9,750:1 in favor of *whether or not*, *if or not* having spiked at a little over 1 in 200 in 1823!

Comment: @StoneyB: True, but regardless of whether we might consider this sentence itself to be an *exceptionally* unusual usage, only a brave (or foolhardy) pedant would presume to cite a "grammatical rule" debarring it! :)

Comment: +1 very nice. Part of the answer, of course, is that 'alternativity' is part of the semantics of *whether* - it is, after all, etymologically composed with *other*. By the way, does your Dickensian variation on McCawley's name suggest that you expect something will turn up? :)

Comment: @StoneyB: Oh corks! Will edit. I guess the ole brain was still woozy from trying to even *follow* the "grammar" he was tentatively advancing. But yeah - I do note the *whether / other / either* connection.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dir version: Whether usually implies that it must be one of the options presented, if usually implies that it may be none of them.