# We were discussing (whether / if) to leave early (or not)

Tags: whether-if

I have read many articles, but I don't know why often the verb "**discuss**" is followed by the conjunction "whether," but not "if". Do you confirm that this verb is an exception and after that we have to use always "whether"? 
In other words as an example I believe that:

> - We were *discussing* **whether** to leave early (or not). ***Correct***
> - We were *discussing* **if** to leave early (or not). ***Incorrect***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not the verb *discuss* that makes the second sentence ungrammatical: **We were discussing **if** to leave early (or not)*. It is the infinitive (which is, in our case, *to leave*).

According to *Practical English Usage* (by Michael Swan),

> **621 whether and if**
>   **3 infinitives**
>   *Whether*, but not *if*, is used before *to*-infinitives.
>   　　*They can't decide **whether to get** married now or wait.*
>   　　(NOT <del>*They can't decide if to get married ...*</del>)

Comment: For the rest of whether/if usage, see http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/22288/3281. (This is mainly for others. I think the OP knew it already.)

Comment: Interesting. I have not looked at this topic like this @DamkerngT. Hope natives confirm this idea over this specific example of mine. :) Anyway still I think after some certain verbs (for instance, discuss,) it is not possible or rather grammatical to use "if".

Comment: It's possible, but not common; you could say "we were discussing if it would be okay to leave early", for example.

Comment: @Hellion But that's an ordinary finite-verb clause, not an infinitive.

Comment: @StoneyB, yes, but my point is that the mere presence of "if" does not mean you cannot use it after "discuss", as A-friend was wondering in the comment above.

Comment: @Hellion ah ... But that is properly an answer (and a very valid one - I would upvote it) to OP's question, rather than a comment on DT's answer, which addresses a distinct matter.

Comment: @StoneyB a fair point.  :-)

Comment: We were discussing if to think is to exist, or if it might be more accurate to say "to *observe or be observed* is to exist".

Answer (score 5):

Using *if* after (some form of) *discuss* is certainly possible.  You could say, for example:

> We were discussing if it's okay to leave early.

I would claim that it's more natural to say *whether* there, but *if* is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Whether should be used not if.  The test for whether you can use if is called the inversion test.

Take the sentence "We'll go to the beach if it's sunny."  This sentence can be inverted to say "If it's sunny, we'll go to the beach," with no loss of meaning.

In the sentence "We were discussing if it's okay to leave early," the inversion produces a nonsensical statement:  "If it's okay to leave early, we were discussing."

Accordingly whether should be used not if.

Comment: The sentence _"We were discussing if it's okay to leave early"_ is probably a poor example of this, because _if it's okay to leave early_ is a projected clause; the reported speech means that you can use it in that way.