# adj plus if-clause

Tags: whether-if

Can if-clause be used as a noun clause after an adj?
Does the sentence "She was undecided if she should accept his offer" sound natural to you? Or should I say "She was undecided whether she should accept his offer"?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Both mean the same thing, and completely understandable.

Comment: What about "I am not certain if he is a student or not" and "I am not certain whether he is a student or not"?

Comment: Same meaning, and both are correct.

Comment: See also http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22272/whether-vs-if

Answer (score 1):

> She was undecided if she should accept his offer.

is just a statement of fact, and is OK as is.

> She was undecided whether she should accept his offer **or not**.

Using *whether* usually indicates a choice of two alternatives. Many times you will also find the phrase *whether or not". See the definition of [whether](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/whether) sense 2.
You could also say:

> She was undecided whether **or not** she should accept his offer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific grammatical rule governing how we link ***undecided*** to immediately-following text clarifying exactly what the indecision relates to. But consider these Google Books results...

> *I was undecided **whether** I [should do this or that]* [(2420 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22not%20believe%20at%20all%20in%20God%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22I%20was%20undecided%20whether%20I%22&tbm=bks)
>    *I was undecided **if** I...* [(72 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22not%20believe%20at%20all%20in%20God%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22I%20was%20undecided%20if%20I%22&tbm=bks)
>    *I was undecided **as to whether** I...* [(115 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22not%20believe%20at%20all%20in%20God%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22I%20was%20undecided%20as%20to%20whether%20I%20should%22&tbm=bks)
>    *I was undecided **as to if** I...* [(1 hit)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22not%20believe%20at%20all%20in%20God%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22I%20was%20undecided%20as%20to%20if%20I%20should%22&tbm=bks)
>    *he was undecided **whether** he...* [(2840 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22not%20believe%20at%20all%20in%20God%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22he%20was%20undecided%20whether%20he%22&tbm=bks)
>    *he was undecided **as to whether** he...* [(1410 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22not%20believe%20at%20all%20in%20God%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22he%20was%20undecided%20as%20to%20whether%20he%22&tbm=bks)

Clearly native speakers overwhelmingly prefer ***whether*** over ***if*** in such constructions. Personally, I'm in that "significant minority" who also prefer to include ***as to*** - but that's really style, rather than grammar.

---

In some contexts, there can be a semantic distinction. Paraphrasing [Grammar Girl's examples](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/if-versus-whether),...

> 1: *Squiggly was undecided **whether** he would go out on Friday or Saturday.*
>    2: *Squiggly was undecided **if** he would go out on Friday or Saturday.*

As indicated, I don't much like #2 anyway. But semantically most people would say there's no doubt #1 implies Squiggly definitely *will* go out - he just hasn't yet made up his mind which day. Whereas with #2 it's possible that he's thinking of staying in this weekend.

Note that this does *not* imply you "should" use ***if*** whenever there's only one possible choice (with the unstated alternative ***not*** that choice) - it's just that you *can*. But it's worth being aware of the fact that using ***whether*** instead of ***if*** can avoid potential ambiguity in some contexts.