# If vs. Whether?

Tags: whether-if

I have often come across this confusion when im using English.
Which word ( if or whether) is to be used in what specific contexts?How do they differ in the contexts they are used in?
Or are they just used interchangeably?

Comment: See also: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/22272/3281

Answer (score 2):

They are **not always** interchangeable. If you are confused what to use where, here is a tip:

We generally prefer 'whether' after prepositions. Said that, don't use 'if' in such cases.

> I asked my friend *about* <del>if</del> whether she had an affair.
>
> I am only interested *in* <del>if</del> whether you are working on this project.

If there's more than one alternative, we use 'or' with 'whether'

> Be specific; <del>if</del> whether you want to pain your house from inside **or** outside

While using 'if' or 'whether' take care if you are including 'or not' as another option. The 'or not' **can** go immediately after 'whether' or in the end, but in case of 'or not' following 'if', it is ungrammatical.

> I asked Mike to find out ***whether or not*** she's coming to the party 
>  I asked Mike to find out ***if*** she's coming to the party ***or not***. 
>  I asked Mike to find out ***whether*** she's coming to the party ***or not***.

Comment: In American English one hears this usage frequently: *I asked Mike to find out if she's coming to the party or not.*  "Ask him if he wants it or not."

Comment: It's a subtle point, but in "if she's coming to the party or not", technically *or not* is still following *if*.  What if we changed it to say "'or not' **immediately** following 'if'"?  Or we could make it even simpler: "but 'if or not' is ungrammatical".

Answer (score 1):

"If" and "whether" are not always interchangeable. 
Use if to introduce a condition. In all other circumstances, use whether.
That is the global idea, but this article goes into detail: http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/if_and_whether.htm

Use only **if** to introduce a condition. In all other cases use use **either if or whether**, that is they are interchangeable.

A condition is something that must be satisfied before something else occurs:

If it rains, bring in the tables.
(If it rains = condition)

Add a point if I get the right answer.
(if I get the right answer = condition)

Comment: Your first sentence is correct, but reading the rest of your answer I just can't figure out when are they interchangeable.

Comment: Hi @LucianSava , I quoted a short description to know when "if" and "wether" are interchangeable on my answer.

Comment: Use only **if** to introduce a condition. In all other cases use **use either if or whether**, that is they are interchangeable. If you edit this way I can upvote your answer.

Comment: @LucianSava Done. You are right, it sounds better.